# How to use prefetch_related in django rest api with foreying key and heritage

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I am working on this Django project, it uses heritage and foreign keys for its models.

These are the models:

```
class SetorFii(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Asset(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(
        Category, related_name='categories', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ticker = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    price = models.FloatField()

class Fii(Asset):
    setor_fii = models.ForeignKey(
        SetorFii, null=True, default=None, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="setor_fiis")

Class Crypto(Asset):
    circulating_supply = models.FloatField(default=0) 


class PortfolioAsset(models.Model):
    asset = models.ForeignKey(Asset, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

I would like to get the field `setor_fii` in the `PortfolioAssetSerializer`, That is what I tried without success.

I get this error message: `Cannot find 'setor_fii' on PortfolioAsset object, 'setor_fii' is an invalid parameter to prefetch_related()`

Would like some help to achieve that.

The serializer:

```
class PortfolioAssetSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    category = serializers.CharField(source='asset.category.name')
    setor_fii = serializers.CharField(source='asset.setor_fii.name')

    class Meta:
        model = models.PortfolioAsset
        fields = (
            'id',
            'category',
            'setor_fii'
        )
```

The view

```
class PortfolioAssetList(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = serializers.PortfolioAssetSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        return models.PortfolioAsset.objects.filter(portfolio_id=self.kwargs['pk']).prefetch_related('setor_fii')
```

Comment: `PortfolioAsset` is not connected to anything?

Comment: Hi @BrianDestura, thanks for reply `PortfolioAsset` is connected to `Asset` by ForeignKey
`asset = models.ForeignKey(Asset, on_delete=models.CASCADE)`

Comment: And `Fii` is connected to `Asset` by heritage

Comment: Ah you're right I see it now. I posted an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prefetch `setor_fii`, you will have to go through `asset`. Since `Fii` inherits from `Asset`, `Asset` will have an automatically created one-to-one field named `fii`. You can then use that to access `setor_fii`:

```py
PortfolioAsset.objects.filter(
    portfolio_id=self.kwargs['pk'],
).prefetch_related(
    'asset__fii__setor_fii',
)
```

Also since the whole relationships here are just one to ones, you can use `select_related` instead of `prefetch_related` to get them all in one query (compared to three queries using `prefetch_related`):

```py
PortfolioAsset.objects.filter(
    portfolio_id=self.kwargs['pk'],
).select_related(
    'asset__fii__setor_fii',
)
```

Comment: Thanks @BrianDestura , it worked, very nice to have a less queries solution, it was needed also to update the serializer,  `setor_fii = serializers.CharField(source='asset.fii.setor_fii')`

Comment: Ah yes that's also needed. You might want to use `serializers.CharField(source='asset.fii.setor_fii.name')` instead